# C# PDFsharp: TIFF images drawn without transparency

Tags: c#, transparency, tiff, pdfsharp

When rendering a TIFF image like this (C# and PDFsharp)

```
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
XImage myImg = XImage.FromStream(myImgStream);
gfx.DrawImage( myImg, x, y, s, w );
```

the image is drawn without transparency.
I tried loading the image from file too (XImage.FromFile(myPath)).
If I do the same with a PNG image transparency is drawn correctly.
Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Link to sample image: https://ibin.co/4iBXM9W5hW1l

PDFsharp build is WPF. I haven't tried GDI.

Comment: You do not include a TIFF that allows replicating the issue. Which build of PDFsharp are you using? Have you tried both builds (GDI and WPF)?

Comment: I updated my question with the requested information. For the version of PDFSharp I am not so sure... I installed it from a package named "PDFsharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_50-beta5.zip" - so I guess it's 1.50 beta sth ^^

Comment: I just recognized that the image is actualy not storing any transparency information... Which is pretty much... :D

Comment: So maybe it is time to choose a less accusing question title...

Comment: What's that for? Then the question itself would be irritating. I clearly stated that my asspumtions were wrong and even posted an answere to not confuse anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My image did not store the transparency information - which I just recognized...